# Big Integers and Custom Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-models

I'm somewhat new to Rails and I'm trying to learn about custom validations.

One common requirement in Brazil are CPF/CNPJ/RG fields. They are a type of identification number and follow a specific format.

For example:

CPFs are 11 digit numbers. They follow this pattern: xxx.xxx.xxx-xx

I'm trying to store them in an Integer field but I'm getting (Using Postgres):

> PG::Error: ERROR:  value "xxxxxxxxxxx" is out of range for type
>   integer

What is the proper way to store this? Bigint (How?)? A string?

My second question is:

How can I specify a custom validation (a method) for this field that could be called somewhat like this:

```
class User < AR::Base

   validates :cpf, presence: true, unique: true, cpf: true
```

Comment: Just because something looks like a number and is called a number doesn't mean that it really is a number. An SSN would be a good example, that's actually a string that just happens to contain digit characters; similarly for zip codes and phone numbers. If you don't want to perform arithmetic on something then it probably isn't really a number.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming performance is not critical, strings are fine. That way you can keep the dots and dashes. As mentioned by others in this thread, `bigint` or `numeric` may be far more performant if that's a concern.

If you keep the field a string, you can easily validate it with regex:

```
validates_format_of :cpf, with: /^[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2}$/
```

Comment: I disagree. Even if you store them as strings with an in-database `CHECK` constraint, string comparisons are still slow and inefficient. Additionally, Rails doesn't let you pass `COLLATE` clauses to your queries, so you'll be doing a whole lot of rather expensive collation for what should be a byte-level comparison. Storing as `bigint` or `numeric` is appropriate.

Comment: @Craig: That's absolutely true and perhaps my answer was too absolute. I've edited it to reflect your comments. If OP is looking for the most performant technique, there's no doubt that `bigint` is superior -- though the difference is minor if the field isn't compared or indexed. Keeping it as a string makes validation simple as well. I think in this case OP is just interested in the basic mechanics.

Comment: My tables are not going to be big. But I'll need all CPFs to be unique, so I think strings are not a good option.

Comment: @Guilherme In that case I'd optimize for programmer efficiency over database efficiency. It isn't fast but there's no problem with a unique index on a `VARCHAR`. If you convert to integers of some sort but still require (or allow) that punctuation your Rails model will need to be much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

For small tables, just store as `text` to preserve the format.

For big tables, performance and storage size may be an issue. If your pattern is guaranteed, you may very well store the number as `bigint` and format it on retrieval with [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html):

Write:

```
SELECT translate('111.222.333-55', '.-', '')::bigint
```

This also serves as partial validation. Only digits, `.` and `-` are allowed in your string. The pattern might still be violated, you have to check explicitly with something like [@Michael provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17034417/939860).

Read:

```
SELECT to_char(11122233355, 'FM000"."000"."000"-"00')
```

Returns:

```
111.222.333-55
```

Don't forget the leading `FM` in the pattern to remove the leading whitespace (where a negative sign might go for numbers).

A `bigint` occupies *8 bytes* on disk and can easily store 11-digit numbers.
`text` (or `varchar`) need 1 byte plus the actual string, which amounts to *15 bytes* in your case.
Plus, processing `bigint` is generally a bit faster than processing `text` of equal length..

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would always store these values as `bigint` and apply formatting on input/output (as Erwin suggests) or in the application.

The main reasons are storage efficiency (as Erwin mentions) and efficiency of comparison. When you compare `11111111112` to `11111111113` as `text`, PostgreSQL will use language-specific collation rules that are correct for text, but may not be what you want for numbers. They're also *slow*; a recent question on SO reported a five-fold speed-up in text comparisons by using the `COLLATE "C"` option to force plain POSIX collations; numeric collations are faster again.

Most of these standard numbers have their own internal check-sums, often a variant of the [Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm). Validating these in a `CHECK` constraint is likely to be a good idea. You can implement a Luhn algorithm check against integers pretty easily in PL/PgSQL or plain SQL; [I wrote some samples on the PostgreSQL wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).

Whatever you do, make sure you have a `CHECK` constraint on the column that validates the number on storage, so you don't get invalid and nonsensical values stored.